# How to setup the visual studio app centre to run on visual studio 2017 instead of 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-app-center

My UWP project normally runs on 2017 and throws some errors when running on 2019. This is a known issue. I tried to setting up the build project in app centre and it didn't request me to select any visual studio version but somehow runs it on visual studio 2019.

Looked through the API docs and etc but couldn't find a work around. Is there anything to do about this? Or is this configuration not doable?